# Find value of n^k modulo 10^7 + 7

Tags: java

Giving int n and k. Find the value of n^k modulo 10^7+7.
I 've been trying to do this problem in different ways using the properties of modulo as ( a * b) % c = ( ( a % c ) * ( b % c ) ) % c . Below is my code. Also, I am a new user, if I missed anything please let me know.

```
int res = 1;
int modulo = (int) Math.pow(10,7)+7;
//( a * b) % c = ( ( a % c ) * ( b % c ) ) % c
System.out.println(modulo);
for (int i = 1 ; i <= k; i++){
    res = ((res%modulo)*(n%modulo))%modulo;

}

return res;
```

Comment: What's the question?

Comment: If you don't have problems with this code but are only asking for feedback, this question is off topic on Stackoverflow, but it would be welcomed on https://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 1):

Both solutions below run in *O(log k)*, unlike e.g. the code in the question (*O(k)*), and the [answer by WJS](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61022252/5221149) using `BigInteger`. WJS's code starts getting slow when `k` is 6 digits. Both solutions below returns immediately even when `k` is `Long.MAX_VALUE`.

---

*In the description in this answer, `a^b` means exponentiation, not bitwise xor.*

You're on the right path using

```
(a * b) % c = ((a % c) * (b % c)) % c
```

What you're missing is

```
a ^ (b + c) = (a ^ b) * (a ^ c)
```

#### Recursive solution

Since the goal is to calculate `(n^k) % (10^7 + 7)`, you can calculate this in *O(log k)* time by recursively splitting `k`.

E.g. if `k = 15` then split like this

```
n^15  =  n^8 * n^7
      =  (n^4 * n^4) * (n^4 * n^3)
      =  ...
```

With modulo that means

```
(n^15) % m  =  ((n^8) % m * (n^7) % m) % m
            =  ...
```

If you create a method for calculating `(n^k) % m`

```
int calc(int n, int k, int m)
```

then with `k = 15`, `calc(n, 15, m)` calls `calc(n, 8, m)` and `calc(n, 7, m)` recursively. With memoization, the result has *O(log k)* time complexity.

```
public static int calc(int n, long k) {
    if (n < 0 || k < 0)
        throw new IllegalArgumentException();
    if (n == 0)
        return 0;
    if (k == 0)
        return 1;
    return calc0(n, k, new HashMap<>());
}

private static int calc0(int n, long k, Map<Integer, Integer> cache) {
    Integer cachedValue = cache.get(k);
    if (cachedValue != null)
        return cachedValue;
    int result;
    if (k == 1)
        result = n % MODULO;
    else
        result = (int) ((long) calc0(n, k / 2, cache) * calc0(n, k - k / 2, cache) % MODULO);
    cache.put(k, result);
    return result;
}
private static final int MODULO = 10000007;
```

---

#### Bitwise solution

If you don't like recursion and memoization, you can use bit manipulation. This is actually slightly more efficient than the recursive approach, sometimes using fewer multiplication and remainder operations.

I won't explain it. See if you can figure out how that works.

```
public static int calc(int n, long k) {
    if (n < 0 || k < 0)
        throw new IllegalArgumentException();
    int e = n % MODULO;
    int r = ((k & 1) != 0 ? e : 1);
    for (long i = k >>> 1; i != 0; i >>>= 1) {
        e = (int) ((long) e * e % MODULO);
        if ((i & 1) != 0)
            r = (int) ((long) r * e % MODULO);
    }
    return r;
}
private static final int MODULO = 10000007;
```

---

#### Test

```
System.out.println(calc(282828,292929));
System.out.println(calc(123456789,987654321));
System.out.println(calc(Integer.MAX_VALUE, Long.MAX_VALUE));
```

*Output*

```
6154601
5111924
5910478
```

Comment: Thank you so much, it works. Your solution is nice and full of explanation.

Answer (score 0):

This is easiest.  You can use it to check your other answers.

```
        System.out.println(fnc(282828,292929));
        System.out.println(yours(282828,292929));


    public static BigInteger fnc(int n, int k) {

        int modulo = (int) Math.pow(10, 7) + 7;
        BigInteger res = BigInteger.valueOf(n).pow(k)
                .mod(BigInteger.valueOf(modulo));
        return res;
    }
```

And here is your solution.  You only needed to use `long's`

```
    public static long yours(long n, long k) {
        long res = 1;
        int modulo = (int) Math.pow(10, 7) + 7;
        // ( a * b) % c = ( ( a % c ) * ( b % c ) ) % c

        // pull out n % modulo since n never changes.
        long nmod = n% modulo;
        long res = nmod%modulo;
        for (int i = 1; i < k; i++) {
            res = ((res% modulo)*(nmod))%modulo;
        }
        return res;
    }
```

They both print

```
6154601
6154601
```

Slight optimizations.

- pull out `n % modulo` as `nmod`.  Just compute once.
- since `1 % modulo` is `1` first time thru, just initialize `res` to `nmod % modulo`.  Then just iterate to `i < k` times.

Comment: Sorry, I didn't include the condition which it should return an int result. Thank you for your time.

Comment: All you need to do is cast the result to an `int`.